# Prevent Django SQLite db from being overwritten while pushing to Heroku

Tags: django, git, sqlite, heroku

I've got a Django application that is storing a large amount of data in it's models. The problem is, whenever I deploy to Heroku even if it's a small change, the remote database with the correct data gets overwritten with the local database of dummy data.

Scenario:

I have a db file `my_db` which is remote. Now, when pushing to heroku, I just `git add` > `git commit` only the files with the changes rather than the whole project. My problem lies in the fact that, it somehow still overwrites remote database with local data.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Heroku [does not provide a persistent filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem).

Most Heroku applications that I have worked on use PostgreSQL for their database, so this isn't a problem. But SQLite is just a file sitting in a directory somewhere, so every time you deploy your database will be lost.

The easiest solution is probably to migrate from SQLite to PostgreSQL, which is very well supported on Heroku (and in Django) and will not lose data every time you deploy.

If you're firmly committed to SQLite you may have some other options:

- Back your database file up before each push and restore it after your push.
- Add your production database to your Git repository, so it will be deployed along with your application (note that I don't recommend this).
- Many users [use Amazon S3 to store other types of assets](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3). You may be able to use a similar procedure with your database, though I suspect there will be some very significant security risks doing so.

Comment: How do you do option #2, which is add your production database to your git repository?

Comment: @devhaven.herokuapp.com, I strongly recommend against this, but you would simply add your database file to your repository like any other file and make sure to commit changes to it as necessary. Note that this option is a particularly bad idea if you intend to modify the database on Heroku: I don't think you can commit updates there, and the ephemeral filesystem might still be a problem. It would work reasonably well if you were using it as read-only settings database, for example. Please seriously consider migrating to PostgreSQL (or another supported client-server database).

Answer (score 0):

You should add the db file to [.gitignore](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files)

Comment: That's a valid answer. However, any idea why does it still overwrite all my files?

Comment: I can only guess as I don't know heroku or how you have your deployment set up.  However, even though you aren't adding or committing the local db file, it looks as though there is still a version of it in your repository. If code changes are deployed via a checkout, that db file will overwrite your production db