# How to stop the data base from being updated in production

Tags: django, database, sqlite, heroku

I am new to Heroku, I have deployed a site from git but the issue is that every time I update the site code, the database also gets updated and all data from my localhost gets in the production, and the data of users from the site is lost. I don't use Heroku ClI and just have simply connected GitHub to Heroku. It's a Django app with a sqlite3 database. I tried .gitignore and git rm --cached too but didn't work. Please tell a way to stop the database file from getting updated when I push it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use a file based database on Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50421061/can-i-use-a-file-based-database-on-heroku)

Comment: See also [Prevent Django SQLite db from being overwritten while pushing to Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23738598/354577), [Django app on Heroku deletes objects after some time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47745393/354577), and many others